# How to convert xls to xlsx using R

Tags: r, excel, file-conversion, openxlsx

I want to convert a bunch of `xls` files to `xlsx` in R so I can use the `openxlsx` package to overwrite in specific cells.

Up until now, I've been changing the format manually by opening each `xls` file and then saving them as `.xlsx`. As you can imagine this is really tiresome and it is kind of manageable now that I have less than 10 files, but I am expecting to have a lot more of these files.

I was wondering if someone has found a way of doing this automatically. I am using R 4.2.1 so the `RDCOMClient` package is not an option (I have read that this could be done easily with that package but it is not available anymore)

**Edit**
I am working with tables within an `Excel` sheet and I need to maintian the format hence the overwriting.

I am familiar with the `openxlsx` package and my main issue is getting the `Workbook` objects out of the `xls` files. That is why I want to convert them into `xlsx` files.

Comment: I am using `read_xls` form `readxl` since my files are `xls`. What I want is to somehow convert them into `xlsx` so I can use the `openxlsx` package to overwrite them since I need a Workbook object and for that, as far as I know, I need `openxlsx`.

Comment: No matter `read_xls` or `read_xlsx`, they read a excel file into R as a dataframe. Then you can use functions in `openxlsx` to do the further things.

Comment: But to use `writeData` or `writeFormula` and then `saveWorkbook` I need a Workbook object and I don't know how turn my `xls` file into one. I can read my files perfectly and do stuff with the data in them, my problem is the overwriting especific cells of the file part.

Comment: After all stuff is done for your `Workbook` object, you can use `saveWorkbook(wb, "abc.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)` to get a new `xlsx` file. It's optional for you to delete the original `xls` file.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but how do I get a `Workbook` object out of a `xls` file?

Comment: I know how to use the `openxlsx` package and it only supports `xlsx` files. I have `xls` files hence my question on how to convert `xls` files to `xlsx` ones.

Comment: No matter the file is `xls` or `xlsx`, they are read in R as a dataframe. You can manipulate this dataframe, and then write it out as a new `xlsx` file with `openxlsx`. So it's unnecessary to convert xls to xlsx when reading the file.

Comment: The thing is I *don't want a new file*. I want to overwrite mine since it has a specific format that I **need** to maintain. My files consist on several tables that I need to fill while keeping the specific format. And to overwrite specific cells I have only found the `openxlsx` package, maybe there's another more appropiate package for what  I need. If so, please if you could help me I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone else is also interested, I really didn't figure out how to do this in R but I did found this https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1349-excel-batch-convert-xls-to-xlsx.html#a2 and I can keep the exact same format from the original file.

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
library(readxl)
library(writexl)

myxls <- list.files(path=".", pattern=".xls")
myxls <- myxls[!grepl("xlsx", myxls)]

for (i in 1:length(myxls)) {
  thisdata <- read_excel(myxls[i])
  newname <- gsub(".xls", ".xlsx", myxls[i])
  write_xlsx(thisdata, newname)
}
```

You will then be able to open each newly created `xlsx` file with `openxlsx`.

---

Edit: for format issues you might take a look at the `rio` package:

```
library("rio")
created <- mapply(convert, myxls, gsub("xlsx", "xls", myxls))
```

I haven't tested it myself, but it might be worth a try.

Comment: That worked perfectly for the data, but I lose all format and the file becomes a bit unreadable for the bureaucracy personal that will need to read my file.

Comment: you might indeed have to do some modifications to `thisdata` in R in order to keep your desired format. Unfortunately, this is not something that is done out-of-the box like when you save as xlsx from excel.

Comment: That is what I feared, yes. Thanks anyways, you helped me a lot with another project where format is not required and this is just perfect!

Comment: I edited my answer with another possibility

Comment: I tried it but it came out with an error: 'Error: Format not supported'. I hadn't heard about the `rio` package before so I'll look into it anyways. Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that can be used to convert XLS files to XLSX :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
convert_XLS_File_To_XLSX <- function(path_XLS_File, path_XLSX_File)
{
  xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
  xlApp[['Visible']] <- FALSE
  xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_XLS_File)
  xlWbk$SaveAs(path_XLSX_File, 51)
  xlWbk$Close()
  xlApp$Quit()
}
```

Comment: Install the package using `install.packages("RDCOMClient", repos = "http://www.omegahat.net/R", type = "win.binary")`

Answer (score 0):

Try ssconvert which comes with the free [gnumeric](http://gnumeric.org/) spreadsheet.  It may issue warnings but will likely work despite that.

Given that you would considering RDCOMClient we assume you are using Windows so use this code modifying the `ssconvert<-` line appropriately for the location of ssconvert on your system.

```
files <- c("a.xls", "b.xls", "c.xls")
ssconvert <- r"{"C:\Program Files (x86)\Gnumeric\1.12.17\bin\ssconvert.exe"}"
for(f in files) shell(paste(ssconvert, print(f), sub("xls$", "xlsx", f)))
```